# How to grayout some of the combobox items and that should be blocked from selection

Tags: wpf

I have two collection of strings.1st collection set as itemsource and other collection contains the items to be disabled.My combobox is given below.

```
<ComboBox Name="txtToolName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,42,0,0" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="260" 
             Grid.Column="1" >
    </ComboBox>
```

How can I display the combobox with disabled items.And the disabled items should not be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't work with two separate collections. Instead, create one collection, where item data and selectable information are combined.

```
IEnumerable<string> entries;
IEnumerable<string> disabled;
txtToolName.ItemsSource = entries.Select(x => new { Value = x, IsSelectable = !disabled.Contains(x) }).ToList();
```

Note this anonymous type `Select` is only for purpose of demonstration. You should use some proper type for the combined data.

You can set `ComboBoxItem` property `IsEnabled` to `False` in order to disable selection.

```
<ComboBox Name="txtToolName" SelectedValuePath="Value" DisplayMemberPath="Value">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsSelectable}"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: @AnuHardin you should mark it as answer if it is working for you.

Comment: Sorry.I don't have the permission to mark it as an answer since my reputation is less than 15.Once i get it i can do that.

Comment: @AnuHardin I think you are mixing up between the "Vote Up privilege" and the ability to accept an answer. The vote up privilege requires 15 rep. but you should always be able to accept answers to your question. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

If you rely on having two separate collections for some reason you could still do this if you set the ItemsSource property of the ComboBox to a CompositeCollection that contains the two collections:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    List<string> yourEnabledCollection = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
    enabledItems.Collection = yourEnabledCollection.Select(s => new { Value = s, IsEnabled = true });

    List<string> yourDisabledCollection = new List<string> { "d", "e", "f" };
    disabledItems.Collection = yourDisabledCollection.Select(s => new { Value = s, IsEnabled = false });
}
```

---

```
<ComboBox Name="txtToolName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,42,0,0"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Value">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=OneTime}"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <CollectionContainer x:Name="enabledItems" />
            <CollectionContainer x:Name="disabledItems" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```